# Doing 110 pull ups in a row non stop

Tags: strength, strength-training, pull-ups, endurance, chin-ups

How does the average Joe and the plain Jane train and prepare to do 110 pull ups in a row non-stop super strict form and no hanging rest,both hands always holding the bar and at least one repetition every 2 seconds?

How do the Athlete Joe and the Athlete Jane train to achieve the exact same feat of strength?

Athlete Joe/Jane is by no means a strong person but on a good day can do 30 reps in a row maybe one more at best and finds it hard to progress further from there. Athlete Joe/Jane can be considered a beginner overall but slightly more proficient at upper body exercises than the average Joe/jane .

Requirements are as follows:

- the methods must be time efficient and not result in overtraining

Comment: Is this a real problem you face? What's your current ability? Why are you asking about two different people?

Comment: 30+ pull-ups is falling into elite athlete territory. What you are suggesting is world record material, especially since basically every pull-up record was achieved with partial range of motion or awful form.

Comment: @JustSnilloc if you call this https://youtu.be/GECFxAq9CBY bad or partial form....

Comment: @JustSnilloc I can already do more than 30 pull ups strict form in a row and I'm basically a beginner....

Comment: @JustSnilloc the problem is, I can not seem to get better

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I also want to train my brother, he's stuck at 6 in a row (he's 10 years old)

Comment: Wait, so you're asking how to beat the pullup world record by five reps? As a beginner? Because you want to train your ten year old brother? I dont even

Comment: That record seemed legitimate, most don’t though. As I already mentioned you’re talking about world record territory, far beyond what most will ever come close to. This site is useful for understanding what’s normal and what isn’t. https://strengthlevel.com/strength-standards/pull-ups/lb

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger - However hypothetical the end result might be, I'd say the core of the question is valid: How does a beginner best train to increase their reps on pullups? Though I concede that the question looks a bit strange.

Comment: @Alec I don't challenge the validity of the question. However, I read it as "How does a beginner best train to increase their reps on pullups *up to top 0.1% athletes territory*". And I doubt this is something that can be answered in a satisfying manner in a few paragraphs on a q&a site by complete strangers.

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger did top athletes become so by chance or is there a method?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I'm not one. Who knows, maybe asking a question on the internet and following three paragraphs of generic advice was all they really needed. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger if they followed normal average advice then the disparity between advanced athletes and world records would be significantly smaller.

Comment: They stop being average, and most likely never were.

Comment: Pull-ups with "at least one rep every 2 seconds" are actually of the easy kind, that's for posers. Try doing them slowly (5 seconds up, 5 seconds down), you're awesome if you can do 8 or 9 (if you do 20, you're probably world class). Most people doing "silly number of reps" pull-ups don't do them properly, they rather "fall" down, and then use rebound to do 1/3 the way up again, which is kinda cheating...

Comment: Worded differently, the challenge in doing pull-ups is getting blood in the muscle as it is a quasi-permanent contraction with at least 2/3 (rather 3/4 for Joe Normal) of max contraction, with rest, and thus blood flow only at two points. Doing fast cheater reps with very short phases of contraction and using momentum works around that, so you can do silly amounts. But that's doing it without doing it, really.

Comment: @Damon never heard anyone doing 10 seconds pull ups...sounds gimmicky

Comment: For a world record attempt, try it at altitude, but inside.  Is supplemental oxygen permitted?    If this were Worldbuilding.SE you'd set the scene on Mars or the Moon.

Comment: @Bes I'm confused. You can already do 30 pull-ups and a one-arm chin, yet this question is supposedly about beginners?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann yep

Comment: @user33399: I'm doing these, they're less gimicky than you think. They're the _actual_ thing. Fast reps is just for showing off in front of girls, it's what every loser can do. Slow reps are what is really demanding (especially if you do the excentric movement slowly, too). Try it, you'll believe you're going to die!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How does [someone] prepare to do 110 pull ups in a row

Start by recognizing this as an extreme goal. I bet the people achieving >75 pull-ups got there by doing gymnastics or bar calisthenics for *years*. Coming even close to this number of pull-ups in one set is such a rare skill that you shouldn't ask anyone who hasn't done it. (Elite training is so *incredibly different* from even advanced intermediate training that usually-helpful answers stop making sense.)

Someone who does a hundred pull-ups in a set *loves pull-ups*. Their motivation to do pull-ups is not just better than anyone they know, it's better than anyone in their country--in the whole world. They may enjoy training for pull-ups more than they enjoy anything else in the world. **You don't know if you like training for pull-ups *at all.***

What I recommend is this: get acquainted with pull-ups. Get moderately good at them then decide whether you love the process (not the goal!) so much that you're willing to sacrifice unreasonable amounts of time, effort, and relationships to work on it. Then decide if more pull-ups are still your goal.

Here's what I'd try: begin with fitting 100 pull-ups into every workout. Then fit those reps into as few sets as possible. Try all the different grips, and prove to yourself that you're at least good at all of them, even if you have a favorite. Then increase the total number of pull-ups -- I'd add 10 every week until I doubled it. At the same time I'd start doing some workouts with pull-up variants: weighted, one-arm progressions, holds, archers, playing with tempo and partial reps, and so on. After this point you'll have to get a little creative, a little crazy: start optimizing your bodyweight for this task, and finding accessory exercises which address your weak points. By now you may have experienced a training injury forcing you to get familiar with some anatomy and amateur physical therapy or other medical or medical-adjacent topics.

Comment: Why would elite training be different? As far as I’m aware for strength training they don’t even have an excessive number of training sessions. Overall training volume also seems to be surprisingly low.

Comment: @Michael Beginner and elite training are *extremely* different. Novices need GPP and a slow ramp-up of training volume, and do well with linear increases in intensity. Advanced training is the opposite in many (most?) disciplines, especially strength sports. I could be wrong but as I understand it, similar training differences are present in gymnastics.

Comment: I just don’t see how elite training would be fundamentally different. Of course for a total beginner basically any exercise in any form will lead to an improvement, but when done properly it’s still all about managing intensity, proper form, volume, recovery, injury prevention etc. etc. Maybe the focus will be more on some areas, but I can’t think of any factor which is totally irrelevant for a beginner while being important for an elite and vice versa.

Comment: I would also point out that this sort of goal is best served by hiring a coach who specializes in this sort of thing. That’s how it works with basically any sufficiently high level sport. To reach such heights, expert assistance is invaluable.

Comment: @Michael I guess if you abstract over the entire process then novice training does indeed deal with the same topics as elite training, but my point is that the implementation details are basically not the same in any way. As I understand it this it basic sports science so I'm not sure where we misunderstand each other.

Answer (score 4):

You could keep your bodyweight mass down, lose fat if you have any, and do several lat exercises such as landmine rows with t bar, or lat bars, one armed rows, etc. Use an endurance type rep scheme(15-20). Working your forearm strength and grip as well as core and biceps to some degree with additional training. Try adding weight here and there but focus more on increasing reps since this is your goal. Outside of this.. just do 6 sets of amap reps of pullups a couple times a week and try to increase your numbers each time. If you fail, stop and start a new set. At the end of the month., try the pull up challenge again. Eventually you'll hit a very high number of reps to where muscular endurance and cardio are going to be the factors that get you that high. You will have to truly work on yourself, and be very lean. Try to not gain too much muscle, even losing muscle in legs might help you.

Reevaluate where you are at the end of each month.. what breaks first, your grip, energy, back, shoulders? And work on those things first.

To reach record high nymbers, you'll have to lose as much weight as you can while keeping your muscles strong. You'll potentially even have to lose muscle in places that don't matter just to she'd a few pounds off such as chest, triceps, legs, etc..

Genetics can play a key role too.. for instance a 5'4 person is going to weigh less and be more mechanically advantages to do more pullups than a 6,0 person

Comment: "you'll have to lose as much weight as you can " - getting "lucky" with some illnesses requiring surgical intervention might help. Having had my complete large intestine removed a couple of years ago, I came out of the operating theater about 10kg lighter than I went in, probably with no consequence for muscle strength to do pullups (and the recovery time after the op was only a couple of weeks). Having your legs amputated would also save quite a bit of irrelevant body mass!

Comment: I think losing weight is one of the keys here. Imagine doing pull-ups with two or three large buckets of water attached to your feet -- that's average Joe's body mass compared to a person with optimal weight. And going for extremes like this record you may need an optimized body *for this specific record* as well. No legs would be best; if that's against the rules, make them as small as you can.

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

If you can do 100 pullups, unless you're doing it to prove a point or show off, training to do 110 is a huge waste of time, because the majority of your time is spent slowly reaching your limit, at which point gains can be made.

Instead, make the exercise harder until you're reaching your limit at, say, ten reps.  For pullups, perhaps make moves towards one-armed pullups, starting with doing them from side to side, progressing to holding on to a towel with one arm instead of the bar, etc.

Comment: I can already do one arm pull ups...I could argue that training to do anything is really a waste of time

Comment: You've not paid any attention to what I said.  "make the exercise harder until you're reaching your limit at ten reps".  If one arm pull ups aren't hard enough to find that limit, then add weight.  (Also I suspect you of lying).

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to do that many.
I have been as high as 30 consecutive and clean all the way down all the way up fast at the same time doing 5 with only right hand and 4 with only left.

A few things that helped me progress:

-Start at the top with your chin above the bar and slowly lower yourself down.  Do this one handed with both hands(if you can do so without hurting yourself, if not work up to it). IMO you should be doing 25 with perfect form before going for one handed.  The point between where your arm is straight and where it is bent at about 30 degrees is the hardest to move through(why you see so many people avoid this part of the motion all together).  You want to be able to lower yoursef easily and slowly through this range eventually with one hand and have that motion as part of your exercise.

-Hang from one arm(do two if you can not do this safely) fully extended and lift your body with your shoulder, neck and lat, those are the muscles that initially propel you into the range where the muscles in your arm can fully engage.

-Do pull-ups, chin-ups and these exercises every day until you CAN NOT do another one, then hang there and pull hard for 10 or 15 seconds like your life depends on it.  You have really got to want it, and it will hurt every day.

-Take very good care of your body and take care not to injur yourself

Good luck, hope you get there